# New Angle When Opposite Side is Halved

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Suppose you have a right triangle with any length sides. The value of one of the angles is $\theta$ and the opposite side is *a*. If I change the triangle so that the new length of side *a* is $\frac a2$, does the new value of $\theta$ always become $\frac \theta 2$?

Comment: Does the hypotenuse change as well, and the other side remains the same?

Comment: Only side _a_ is intentionally changed, but changing one leg and not the other forces the hypotenuse to change as well.

Comment: Yes, I see, then the answer below can't be correct.

Comment: @Danijel If $\sin\theta = \frac{a}{c}$, then halving will give $\sin\theta_1 = \frac{a}{2\sqrt{c^2-\frac3{4a^2}}}$. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

No, but close. $\sin \theta$ becomes $\frac{1}{2}\sin \theta$. In the limit angle goes to zero this becomes the same as $\theta$ becoming $\frac{\theta}{2}$, so it's a good approximation for right triangles with one side disproportionally small compared to others.